How to use material-ui styled components inside Next.js server components
I'm using Next.js version 14 with app router alongside with Material-UI v5.
Whenever I'm rendering Material-UI components in server pages components It's working just fine. The issue starts when I'm trying to style these components with styled function from @mui/material package.
I'm using the emotion engine under the hood as the engine for MUI as you can see here:
"Material UI uses Emotion as its default styling engine."
The issue that I can see on the browser is:
"Error: Attempted to call styled() from the server but styled is on the client. It's not possible to invoke a client function from the server, it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component."

The versions of the relevant packages that I'm using:
"@emotion/cache": "^11.11.0",
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
"@mui/material": "^5.15.15",
"@mui/material-nextjs": "^5.15.11",
"next": "14.2.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",

Thank you for your help.

I don't know if it's the recommended approach but from what I read you are supposed to add a 'use client' at the top of any sub-component that requires it. For example, if you have a styled component, separate it into its own file and add the 'use client'. The parent page could still use SSR, but load client components into it.
At least it will solve the error you mentioned using styled from MUI or Emotion.
Example:
'use client'
import { Button } from '@mui/material'
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'

export const MainButton = styled(Button)`
  width: 200px;
`

